# Incluir código PHP dentro de echo PHP

Tags: php

Sé que la pregunta suena un poco fuera de toda lógica, pero al intentar muchas opciones sin éxito ( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921479/include-whole-content-of-a-file-and-echo-it) [2](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/como-meter-php-dentro-echo-972582/) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228026/can-you-put-php-inside-php-with-echo) ) acudo a esSO para buscar su ayuda.

Tengo mi `navbar` en un archivo PHP al que llamo con la sentencia `include` en todas mis demás páginas.

Hago el llamado así:

```
<head>
<style>...</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php include "include/navbar.php"; ?>
...
<script>...</script>
</body>
```

Y mi `navbar.php` está así:

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
<li>Inicio</li>

<?php if ($_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 1){?>
<li>Admin</li> <?php }?>
</ul>
</div>
```

El código funciona bien tal cual, la sentencia que hago al Menú Admin es validar si el usuario tiene permisos para ver o no ese menú. Esos datos los pido con PDO en un formulario de inicio de sesión, pero eso ya es salirnos del tema.

El problema con dicho código es que por algún motivo (el menú en `navbar.php` es mucho más largo) cuando cargo cada página se desordena el CSS y el orden de carga de la página.

Logré solucionar el desorden y la falla en carga metiendo ese navbar en un `echo`, así:

```
<?php 
 echo
'
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
<li>Inicio</li>

<?php if ($_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 1){?>
<li>Admin</li> <?php }?>
</ul>
</div>

'
?>
```

El problema es que de esta forma, pierdo la sentencia en PHP, aparentemente debería ser texto plano, lo extraño es que el navegador lo oculta, podría pensar que es porque si funciona, pero no es así, porque siempre se muestra el menu admin.

**¿Cómo puedo incluir dicha sentencia PHP dentro de un echo?**

¿Me sugieren otra forma de hacerlo?

Si me pregunta incumple las reglas de sitio cómo:

- Creación de ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable
- Demasiado amplia
- Basada en opiniones

Les ruego me hagan saber, para así replantear mi pregunta, de lo contrario, si se entiende el objetivo, estoy agradecido en su ayuda.

Buen día!

Comment: ¿Porque simplemente no cierras tu echo y continuas el <? php ?> ?

Comment: lo que estás haciendo con el include está bien, pero verifica que navbar.php no tenga CSS, que este simplemente como lo especificaste en tu respuesta. (sin: <html>;<head>;<body>)

Comment: Gracias Kevin, no lo expliqué correctamente, el CSS se desordena pero es cosa de 3 o 5 segundos, mientras carga por completo la página. No tiene estilos CSS el include.

Comment: Gracias JiMel, mi código es muy extenso y aunque lo intenté en principio, incluso escapando las etiquetas me fue dificil manejarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mezcla de código PHP/HTML con constantes aperturas y cierres de bloque produce un código confuso, difícil de analizar y de corregir cuando hay errores.

Para evitarlo puedes concatenar todo en una variable (`$html` en este caso), y así trabajar todo el tiempo dentro de un sólo bloque PHP. Al final imprimes la variable que has ido concatenado.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $html=
    '<div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Inicio</li>';
    if ( $_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 1 ){
        $html.='<li>Admin</li>';
    }
    $html.=
        '</ul>
    </div>';
    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Perfecto, me costó varios intentos poder implementarlo al código real pero funciona de maravilla, incluso creo que hasta carga más rápido jajaja. Mil Gracias!