# Ocultar o Mostrar tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql, tablas

Tengo el siguiente codigo para un boton abrir y cerrar

El cual esta dentro de un td de una tabla y dentro de este td estoy mostrando otra tabla lo que me interesa hacer es que solo me muestre la tabla cuando el boton este en estatus de abierto y cuando este en cerrado la tabla no se muestre

```
<td>
<?php 
if($course['status']=="1") 
echo
"<div style='background: #c69b7c;'>
Abierto <a href=desactivate.php?id=".$course['id']." class='btn gray'></a>";

else
echo 
"<div style='background:#E3DFDB;'> Cerrado <a href=activate.php?id=".$course['id']."
class='btn brown'></a>";
?>

\\\Esta tabla es la que quiero mostrar solo cuando este el estatus abierto
<table class="ra" id="rampas">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>Destino</th>
<th>Trailer</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php 
if (count($ramp) > 0) {
$count = 1;
foreach ($ramp as $row) {
?>
<tr>
<td align=center><?= $count++ ?></td>
<td><?=$row['plant_code']?></td>
<td><?=$row["trailer"]?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

Ya intente lo siguiente:

Añadi la tabla en la seccion del if donde valida si el estatus es abierto pero no funciono aun en estatus de cerrado siguio mostrandolo.

De igual forma intente mandar a llamar la tabla desde otro archivo con un script y que solo se mostrara en el if pero no funciono.

Si pudieran ayudarme lo agradeceria u orientarme les dejo un gif del proceso del codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso tendrias que hacerlo del lado del cliente

Comment: Hola alberto, te comento que esa funcion la puedes realizar desde el cliente, por lo tanto no hay un backend como tal, si utilizas jQuery te recomiendo usar funciones `async` para solamente cargar la informacion que el cliente solicite

Comment: Esta validación solo funciona al renderizar la pagina, y no te permite dinamismo en el front, si quieres poder abrir y cerrar las rampas desde el front, tu código actual no funciona, debes imprimir tanto la tabla como el **close** y ocultar por medio de JS, idealmente  dispares una acción cuando el boton se presione y este puede ocultar o volver a mostrar la tabla al cambiar la clase (por ejemplo), te puedes apoyar del id de la tabla para esto.

Comment: @RenyRamos gracias hare la prueba asi como dices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucione el enigma de la siguiente manera con ayuda de uno de los usuarios de aqui que me dio las bases.

Anexo el codigo final por si le llega a servir a alguien mas:

```
<?php

$view2 = "SELECT * FROM plan_embarque WHERE rampa = 'RAMPA #1' ORDER BY prog_date ASC LIMIT 8";
    
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $view2);

$statement = $link->prepare($view2);
$statement->execute();
$ras2 = $statement->get_result();

$ramp2 = array();

while ($item = $ras2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ramp2[] = $item;
}

//Extraer todas la filas y almacenarlas en una tabla
$table = "<table class='ra' id='rampas'>\n";
$table .= "<tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Destino</th><th>Trailer</th></tr>\n";
if (count($ramp2) > 0) {
    $count = 1;

    foreach ($ramp2 as $row) {

$table .= "<tr>
<td>".$count++."</td>
<td>".$row["plant_code"]."</td>
<td>".$row["trailer"]."</td>
      
   </tr>\n";
    }
}
$table .= "</table>\n"; 
  
?>
```

La tabla donde muestro el boton y muestro la tabla secundaria quedo asi mande a llamar a la tabla dentro del if que revisa si esta abierta o cerrada

```
<td>
<?php 
if($course['status']=="1")
echo "<div style='background: #c69b7c;'> Abierto <a href=desactivate.php?id=".$course['id']." class='btn gray'></a> $table";
                    
else 
echo"<div style='background:#E3DFDB;'> Cerrado <a href=activate.php id=".$course['id']." class='btn brown'></a>";
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que aplicar la misma validación que tienes arriba, si el estado es `abierto`, se mostrará la tabla, de lo contrario, no se mostrará:

```
<td>
<?php 
if($course['status']=="1") 
echo
"<div style='background: #c69b7c;'>
Abierto <a href=desactivate.php?id=".$course['id']." class='btn gray'></a>";

else
echo 
"<div style='background:#E3DFDB;'> Cerrado <a href=activate.php?id=".$course['id']."
class='btn brown'></a>";
?>
<?php
  if($course['status']=="1")
    echo
    '<table class="ra" id="rampas">
      // . . .
    </table>';
?>
</td>
```

Comment: Gracias hare la prueba y te aviso si me funciono

Comment: Veo que tienes lógicas php dentro de la tabla que quieres ocultar, revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231488/incluir-c%C3%B3digo-php-dentro-de-echo-php) para que lo puedas aplicar correctamente. Yo lo intenté hacer (revisa el historial de mis ediciones) pero no estoy completamente seguro si es correcto, el motivo es que ando fuera de casa y el ordenador donde estoy no tiene php instalado, de la cual no puedo verificarlo con exactitud.

Comment: Por mientras ve probando con una tabla sin la lógica php que lleva dentro.

Comment: Con una sin php funciono bien pero con mis valores que extraigo de mysql me arroja error en las lineas que tienen php tal y como dijiste

Comment: Claro, era lo que suponía. Como te comentaba, hay una solución para poder integrar los valores y funciones php dentro de la validación (hice un intento en mi historial de ediciones, me basé en la pregunta que te adjunté en la respuesta de arriba).

Comment: Ya revise las ediciones use la 2da edicion pero me dice que variable tabla infenida no toma en cuenta que la variable es igual a tabla je

Comment: Claro, solo faltaría investigar un poco. Si encuentro una solución, le avisaré y editaré mi respuesta (o capaz hago otra) :).

Comment: gracias ya pude de echo añadi como quedo al final en otra respuesta